# ¿Por qué las opciones no se generan en pantalla?

Tags: lua

Tengo las siguientes lineas de codigo en el archivo nivel1.lua:

```
 require ('principal')
 local i=1

 --Lectura de Archivos
 local mfdo="media/fd1.png"

 local inst = io.open("nivel_1/instruccion.txt","r")
 local minst={}
 for line in inst:lines() do 
    minst[i] = line
    i=i+1 
 end

 local opc1 = io.open("nivel_1/opcion1.txt","r")
 local mopc1={}
 for line in opc1:lines() do 
    mopc1[i] = line
    i=i+1 
 end

 objdib=objetos:new()
 objdib:dibujar(mfdo, minst, mopc1,1)
```

El problema está en que en pantalla solo puedo visualizar el fondo (argumento `mfdo`) y la instrucción (argumento `minst`). Las opciones no se generan en pantalla y solo llega hasta instrucción. ¿Qué puede estar pasando?

Y las siguientes son líneas de código de la clase principal:

```
-- Meta class
objetos = {fdo, inst, img, opc1, opc2, opc3, opc4, ok, ejer, pal, x}

-- Base class method new
function objetos:new (o, fdo, inst, img,  opc1, opc2, opc3, opc4, ok, ejer, pal,x)
    o = o or {}
    setmetatable(o, self)
    self.__index = self
    self.fdo = fdo 
    self.inst = inst 
    self.img = img 
    self.opc1 = opc1 
    self.opc2 = opc2 
    self.opc3 = opc3 
    self.opc4 = opc4 
    self.ok = ok
    self.ejer = ejer 
    self.pal = pal
    self.x =x 
    return o
   end


   -- Clase base para dibujar elementos
   function objetos:dibujar (mfdo, minst, mopc1,x)

       local mifondo = canvas:new(mfdo);
       canvas:new (5, 5);
       canvas:compose(0, 0, mifondo);
       canvas:flush()

       canvas:attrColor('red')
       canvas:attrFont('Tiresias','40','normal')
       canvas:drawText(300,100,minst[x])
       canvas:flush()


       **--Esta parte ya no se genera???!!!**
       canvas:attrColor('red')
       canvas:attrFont('Tiresias','40','normal')
       canvas:drawText(400,100,mopc1[x])
       canvas:flush()
   end
```

Comment: por favor lee [ask] y el [tour] para ver cómo preguntar de una manera eficiente. Titular con el problema es mucho mejor que con algo genérico. Proporciona un [mcve], describe cómo lo ejecutas y qué error exacto ves.

Comment: Amigo es que no se ni como titularlo porque no se cual es el problema!!! tengo un codigo de ejemplo y ese me trabaja bien y este no... le he dado vueltas toda la noche, inclusive lo volvi a programar linea a linea y no encuentro el error!!!

Comment: Para poder ayudarte es fundamental que digas qué probaste y qué ejecutas exactamente. Así podremos al menos replicar el problema.

Answer (score 0):

Del código he notado que en la clase `objetos` la función dibujar requiere otra clase que es `canvas` como lo veo al crear nuevos objetos `objdib=objetos:new()` y dibujarlos `objdib:dibujar(mfdo, minst, mopc1,1)` no se aprecia que el `objdib` sea hijo de una clase para renderizado (Jerarquía) por ejemplo algo así:

```
--[[

Hierarchy example. It uses sprites to group another sprites.

This code is MIT licensed, see http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
(C) 2010 - 2011 Gideros Mobile 

]]


dot1tex = Texture.new("dot-1.png")
dot2tex = Texture.new("dot-2.png")
group1tex = Texture.new("group-1.png")
group2tex = Texture.new("group-2.png")

group1 = Sprite.new()

group1:addChild(Bitmap.new(group1tex))

for i=0,3 do
    for j=0,3 do
        local dot = Bitmap.new(dot1tex)
        dot:setPosition(i * 45 + 10, j * 45 + 60)
        group1:addChild(dot)
    end
end

group1:setPosition(10, 10)
stage:addChild(group1)


group2 = Sprite.new()

group2:addChild(Bitmap.new(group2tex))

for i=0,3 do
    for j=0,3 do
        local dot = Bitmap.new(dot2tex)
        dot:setPosition(i * 45 + 10, j * 45 + 60)
        group2:addChild(dot)
    end
end

group2:setPosition(100, 200)
stage:addChild(group2)
```

Si observas todos es agregado al `stage` (padre) para el renderizado, teniendo en cuenta como dije previamente la [Jerarquía](http://giderosmobile.com/examples#Graphics/Hierarchy)